# Migrate map function from rxjs5 to rxjs6

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to migrate the following code from rxjs5 to rxjs6:

```
return this.http.put(url, image, options).map((res, err) => {
      return res;
    }).catch(err => {
      if (err.error instanceof Error) {
        return err.error;
      } else {
        throw Observable.throw(err);
      }
    });
```

I came with this solution:

```
return this.http.put(url, image, options).pipe(map((res, err) => {
      return res;
    }));
```

But the problem is that I don't know if I'm not migrating the `.catch` part of the code.

Can you suggest the best way to migrate the following code?

Comment: Well just add `.catch` part after pipeing?

Comment: catch() => catchError() catch renamed to catchError()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`catch` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript, so it was renamed to `catchError`. The same with `throw` and `throwError`.

```
return this.http.put(url, image, options).pipe(
  map((res, err) => {
    return res;
  }),
  catchError(error => throwError(error))
);
```